# Table Cell won't align vertically and horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good morning everyone!

I was hoping if any you masters would be able to assist - I have a div on a site I am building  which has been applied with a CSS of "height: 100%" and been given the "display: table" property. There is another div within this div with a "display: table-cell" and a "vertical-align: middle". However, this code is not centering vertically? Additionally, I have a "margin-left: auto" and a "margin-right: auto" applied yet it does not center horizontally either as it should - any thoughts?

I have 4 animations on the page but the one I am working on right now will only display for mobile phones, so you will either need to use this (http://mobiletest.me/#d=iPhone_5_portrait&u=http:// energyamplified.co.za/home.php) or make sure your view port when visiting (http:// energyamplified.co.za/home.php) is within 227-449 pixels wide.

The CSS:

```
#animation_wrapper {
height: 100%;
display: table;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 227px) and (max-width: 449px) { /* Very Small Animation */
div #frameContainer_very_small {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-top: 25%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
div #frameContainer_very_small iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
}
}
```

The HTML/JS (which in this viewport, the css elsewhere on the site loads the iframe "animation_very_small.html":

```
<div id="animation_wrapper">                   
<div id="frameContainer">
<script type="text/javascript">
onload=function(){
var el1=document.getElementById("frameContainer")
el1.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation.html\"></iframe>"

var el2=document.getElementById("frameContainer_medium")
el2.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_medium.html\"> </iframe>"

var el3=document.getElementById("frameContainer_small")
el3.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_small.html\">    </iframe>"

var el4=document.getElementById("frameContainer_very_small")
el4.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_very_small.html\">    </iframe>"

}
</script>
</div>
<div id="frameContainer_medium">
</div>
<div id="frameContainer_small">
</div>
<div id="frameContainer_very_small">
</div>
</div>
```

Your time and assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Byron

Comment: I believe I have solved the horizontal alignment - seems the IFrame needed an absolute width. For the vertical alignment, i have resolved to use padding for now, but as you can imagine this is far from ideal on different view ports - any help on this would still be greatly appreciated

Comment: The iframe has a height of 100%, so it fills the container completely. If you want to center it in the middle, your efforts must be directed to the iframe's source, not the container.

Comment: Thanks Mr Lister. I have  added a set height to the IFrame yet it still makes no difference. I attempted to isolate it here (http://jsfiddle.net/dngkC/) and still it does not work. Any idea why, when I add the height, it still does not center vertically? If you remove the padding and then add the height to the IFrame using Inspect in Chrome or Firebug,  you can see that nothing happens.

Comment: Okay, one of the other divs was causing an issue and after I added the height as suggested, it is working now. Thank you for your direction Mr Lister - feel free to add this as an answer if you want me to mark it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, one of the other divs was causing an issue and after I added the height as suggested, it is working now. Thank you for your direction Mr Lister - feel free to add this as an answer if you want me to mark it for you.